# mouse hover action in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to do mouse hover operation.But this code is working some time and some time not

my code is

```
     driver.get("http:obsessory.com/");
  Actions action = new Actions(driver);
  WebElement mainMenu = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/shop/m/women']"));
     action.moveToElement(mainMenu).build().perform();
```

I have used these xpaths

```
  1)html/body/header/div[3]/div/ul/li[2]/a
  2)//a[text(),'Women')]]
  3).//*[@id='nav']/li[2]/a
```

NOTE : I want to go to site, mousehover on Women and click on dresses.

Answer (score 0):

The page contains 2 occurrences of `//a[@href='/shop/m/women']`. The first one isn't visible. Do you want to click the 2nd one, labeled "WOMEN" in the top menu bar? Then try:

```
//a[@href='/shop/m/women'][ancestor::ul[@id='nav']]
```